# (using 'imgkit' on Ubuntu server) wkhtmltopdf: could not connect to any X display

Tags: python, ubuntu, wkhtmltopdf, xvfb, imgkit

I have a python script running on a remote Ubuntu server. At some point in my code, I create an HTML file which I then convert to a png. I therefore elected to use imgkit, which does the job beautifully well (I tested my code on my Mac OS before uploading the python script to the remote Ubuntu server):

```
import imgkit

imgkit.from_url('MyFile.html', 'MyFile.png')
```

Now, the problem is that the Ubuntu server did not have imgkit and wkhtmltopdf installed. So I ran the following command:

```
sudo pip install imgkit
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

Then it returned the error:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Could not connect to any X display.


You need to install xvfb(sudo apt-get install xvfb, yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb, etc), 
then add option: {"xvfb": ""}.
```

So far so good. I therefore ran the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

Which worked. But the Ubuntu server is still returning the same error. Now, for one thing, I have no idea what: `then add option: {"xvfb": ""}.` even means. I tried to look for answers online and people quoted that before, without explaining what one should actually do or write in the terminal. I also feel that I am missing extensions for wkhtmltopdf but I am not sure which (again, I ran an online search but I am more confused than anything else at this point. I found similar threads on stack overflow, but nothing quite like the problem I am experiencing). Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thank you so very much
Best regards,
Berti

Answer (score 4):

I was able to find the workaround.

Turns out the solution was pretty clear in the message, but we somehow managed to ignore that.

So after using this command `sudo apt-get install xvfb`,

All we have to do is add `{"xvfb": ""}` in options dict and pass that to the method.

For Eg:

```
options={'xvfb': ''}
imgkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.png', options=options)
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the solution to my question: 
`then add option: {"xvfb": ""}`

However I was able to get my code to work. There are two solutions.

1) Use wkhtmltopdf:

```
import os

os.system("xvfb-run -a wkhtmltopdf %s %s"%('filenameIn.html','filenaneOut.png'))
```

That produces a PDF file, without the need to setup a virtual display.

2) Setup a virtual display using pyvirtualdisplay:

```
import imgkit
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(600,600))
display.start()
imgkit.from_file("filenameIn.html", "filenameOut.png")
display.stop()
```

Actually, 2) was answered before and I missed it while searching StackOverflow: ["Could not connect to display" on EC2 Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56264534/could-not-connect-to-display-on-ec2-server/56265484)

Note: you can combine 1) and 2): use wkhtmltopdf to convert to png directly, but with a virtual display (otherwise the png will not show the resulting image, at least it was the case for me).

I thought it could help. :)
Berti

------------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------

I had a mistake (now fixed) in my solution: for 2): it should have been "filenameOut.png" instead of "filenameOut.html